# Error con php failed to open stream: No se puede establecer una conexion

Tags: php, apache

Me pega el fallo en esta linea,he probado poniendo allow_url_fopen y allow_url_include en On , incluso usar la libreria curl pero sigue sin funcionar y ya no se que hacer.

```
// Pedimos al la api que nos devuelva una lista de autores. La respuesta se da en formato JSON
$lista_autores = file_get_contents(urlencode("http://localhost/dwes/rest/api.php? 
action=get_lista_autores"));
// Convertimos el fichero JSON en array
$lista_autores = json_decode($lista_autores, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

quita el urlencode ya que te está reemplazando los caracteres no alfanuméricos por el sigo % por lo que crea la la url http%..., esta función solo debe usarse para pasarse como parametros de consulta, un caso muy particular cuando buscamos una palabra que tiene espacios, ahí es donde es útil usar urlenconde

Comment: lo quite pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: entonces puede que la url esté mal formada